# Handling a textarea component in a NextJS app

Tags: typescript, next.js, textarea

I am having an issue handling the input of a textarea component in a NextJS app.

Here is how the component looks like:

```
<textarea placeholder={pcHld}
          value={fldNm}
          onChange={onChangeVar}
          className="bg-cyan-300"
          rows={3} cols={20} />
```

The problem is on the onChange.

This is how onChangeVar looks:

```
  const onChangeVar = (event: FormEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement>):
    void => {
      console.log('onChangeVar:'+event.name)
      console.log('onChangeVar(JSOD):'+JSON.stringify(event))
  };
```

Here only debugging messages are printed. But the final goal is to be able to get the text contents of the textarea component and do something useful with it.

At this point I hit the error below:

```
Type '(event: FormEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void' is not assignable to type     'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement>'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>' is not assignable to type     'FormEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement>'.
      Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>' provides no match for the signature '(event:    FormEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>): void'.ts(2322)
......
```

or:

```
Type '(event: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement>'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement>'.
      Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>' provides no match for the signature '(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>): void'.
```

I am obviously writing something wrong in the code, since there is a missmatch in the types.

But the few things I tried out failed, so what is the way I should change the code for things to work ?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
const onChangeVar = (event: FormEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement>):
```

To

```
const onChangeVar = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>):
```

While `ChangeEvent` refers to the event object itself, `FormEventHandler` refers to the function.

```
const onChange: FormEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement> = (event) => {}
const onChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement> => {}
```

Comment: I guess the type of function is ChangeEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement> and the type of variable event must be ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>.

Comment: True. I've already updated the answer to clarify that

Comment: The oppisite is true. `ChangeEvent` is the event object and `FormEventHandler` is the function

Comment: I am trying to work from your comments, but with no success for now. For the best I can get rid of the error messages. But can' yet figure out how to print the value of my textarea.